# Why does listening to familiar music create less distraction?

Tags: genre

I have tried concentrating on studies with different music. Classical, rock, pop, everything.
However the only music that didn't distract me was the music I already knew, regardless of its genre. Why is it so? Does your brain create some pattern?

Comment: I believe the answer is already present in your title: **the familiar is less distracting than the unfamiliar.** But I wonder what this has to do with music, intrinsically.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that too, when I want to study I listen only the music I already know. In my opinion the explanation would be that the brain recognises the lyrics and it doesn't need to concentrate to understand the music message anymore so that you can pay attention to something else.